# Javascript used to work but now it doesn't

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

This javascript worked before but just today, it doesn't. I tried adding alert() inside the functions.js but it doesn't pop up anymore. My javascript is enabled and pop up is enabled, too.

footer.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery/functions.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery/jquery.validate.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery/additional-methods.js') ?>"></script>
```

functions.js

```
$("document").ready(function(){
alert("sfs");
$('#type').change(function () {
    if ($('#type').val() == 'fund') {
        $('#fund').show();
        $('#submit').show();
    } else if ($('#type').val() == 'attendance') {
        $('#fund').hide();
        $('#submit').show();
    } else {
        $('#fund').hide();
        $('#submit').hide();
    }
});
$("addmember").validate({
    rules: {
        id: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
        }
        lname: {
            required: true
        }
        fname: {
            required: true
        }
        mname: {
            required: true
        }
        contact: {
            digits: true
        }
        email: {
            email: true
        }

    }
});
```

});

tnew.php

```
<div id="content">
<center>
<h1>New Transaction</h1>
<?php echo form_open("home/transact"); ?>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Transaction" name="name" id="name" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Type:</td>
        <td><?php 
                $options = array(
                    'select' => '(Select Type)',
                    'fund'  => 'Funds',
                    'attendance'    => 'Attendance'
                );
                $id = 'id = "type"';
                echo form_dropdown('type', $options, 'select', $id);
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fund" style="display: none;">
        <td>Amount: </td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="Amount" name="amt" id="amt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="submit" style="display: none;">
        <td colspan = 2><?php echo form_submit("submit", "Add Transaction"); ?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</center>
```

Dropdown used to work but now, it doesn't. I'm also using codeigniter if that's an issue.

Comment: did you check js file path in hrml source?

Comment: Do you get any js errors when loading the page?

Comment: something as changed from yesterday to today obviously. Check console/network tab, any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your rules are missing the comma (,) between your field configuration, it should be

```
$("addmember").validate({
    rules: {
        id: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
        },
        lname: {
            required: true
        },
        fname: {
            required: true
        }
        mname: {
            required: true
        },
        contact: {
            digits: true
        },
        email: {
            email: true
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

site_url return url with `index.php`. so your js path may throw 404 error. You should use base_url.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery/functions.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery/jquery.validate.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery/additional-methods.js') ?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this declaration  `$(document).ready(function(){});`